# How can a javaagent be prevented from attaching?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

How can one check if a javaagent is injected into the JVM or disable attaching of javagents?
I'm trying to prevent my application from being modified at runtime due to security reasons.

I know how to prevent a javaagent from being loaded on startup, but I was unable to figure out a way to prevent the VirtualMachine API from dynamically attaching.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: The [java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) specifies quite strict conditions for being able to dynamically attach a javaagent - see "Starting Agents After VM Startup"

It seems to me the answer may be: "by not fulfilling at least one such condition - preferable all". What is your experience? (how come you still have javaagents attaching?)

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi Reading the conditions required, it seems like I can only control one(the classloader). I'm not too confident with Classloaders, so writing my own classloader that prevented agent jars being added to the classpath seems to be a daunting task. In particular, I'd worry about preventing legitimate libraries from being added. Do you have any tips on that?

Comment: Why do you need to do it at all? "In particular, I'd worry about preventing legitimate libraries from being added." Of course. So who but the customer is in the best position to take care about what is legit or non-legit use of extra libraries? In other words, why an emphasized paragraph in the documentation about "how and what" wouldn't be enough? Are you writing a security application? If not, I think is safe to let this responsibility with your users, just document it and let them care.

Answer (score 4):

On HotSpot, you can set `-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism` and on J9, you can disable attachment via `-Dcom.ibm.tools.attach.enable=no` but there is no way to disable it for any VM. What you could do would be to instrument any class with a `premain(String, Instrumentation` method yourself to not be passed an actual instance of the instrumentation interface or `null`. I would however not recommend it, this would break the attach API's general contract.

However, none of this increases security. An attachment requires that another process with privileges to access your JVM process is running on the same machine. If this is the case and this other process is an attacker, the instrumentation API is the last problem you should worry about. Also, if you maintain a library, your library's user has already full access to your code and the possibility to modify it before running your code.

Therefore, even though can can disable attachment, there is no gain in doing so to "increase security".

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, I can always check the hashes of everything matches what it should be, so I can prevent them from changing the library.

Comment: If I can change your library, I can change your hashes. The best you can do here is security by obscurity. If the VM can run your code, I can extract it.

Comment: Except by changing the hashes you are modifying the stored program, which the running program can also check for. As long as there is always a running process with an unmodified runtime, I think it would be quite hard to bypass.

Comment: Not really in case that you control the user running the VM process. As I said before, this would only be security by obscurity.

Comment: @Stoud: the runtime representation of classes changes even without the presence of instrumenting agents, as specified by [`retransformClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses-java.lang.Class...-): “The initial class file bytes represent the bytes passed to `ClassLoader.defineClass` or `redefineClasses` (before any transformations were applied), *however they might not exactly match them*.” So hashing is pointless.

Comment: Another option may be putting hashes somewhere outside (on some http(s) server). But, as @rafael-winterhalter mentioned before, attacker may decompile, deobfuscate, debug, instrument/redefine any class if he has access to it, including making some stubs etc.